# MySQL 5.7 - Under the hood of MySQL PASSWORD() function

Tags: mysql, function, hash, passwords, user-accounts

I am migrating from MySQL 5.5 to 5.7. I would like to understand the algorithm used by the `PASSWORD()` function (which is implicitly and internally called by MySQL) when creating users.

**Tests:**
When I have started my local MySQL 5.7.19 instance, the following command-line print `0` for `old_passwords`:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%old_passwords%';
```

And those two return the same value:

```
SELECT PASSWORD('mypass');
SELECT UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1('mypass'))));
```

When I set the `old_passwords` to `2`, the `PASSWORD()` function returns different values each time I call `SELECT PASSWORD('mypass');`.

**MySQL 5.7.x questions:**

1. What is the easiest way to know the current hash implementation used by MySQL's `PASSWORD()` function?
2. Is `SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1(str)))` the default hash implementation of the `PASSWORD()` function for MySQL 5.7.x? If no, what is the default `PASSWORD(str)` hash implementation?
3. Is it possible to change the `PASSWORD(str)` implementation **with configuration**? If yes, how to change it to SHA256?

Comment: Myswl is open source, so you can check the implementation right in the code.